# Does there exist an efficient way to determine if two $n$-simplices in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are congruent?

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, simplex, congruences-geometry

Given two $n$-simplices in $\mathbb{R}^n$, does there exist an algorithm to determine if they are congruent which has a time complexity of the form $O(n^c)$ where $c$ is a constant?

I'm assuming that given a simplex, no subset of its vertices all have the same coordinates and all vertices are in the convex hull - no degenerate simplices

I'm aware that the general problem for a set of points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is related to the graph isomorphism problem, therefore the answer is still unknown, but I'd like to know about the special case where the points form an $n$-simplex

Comment: Why would you think that forming an $n$-simplex makes the problem any easier?

Comment: @Somos That's a fair question. Honestly, I'm just hoping that there's some property which simplices have that makes this problem easier to solve. Similar to how some graph theory problems become easier if we restrict them to a certain class of graphs, I'm hoping for something similar here. It may be the case that this is as hard as the general problem, but I wanted confirmation that there's nothing I'm overlooking